# How to enable the Widevine in cobalt?

Tags: drm, cobalt, widevine

I want to refer the code flow of widewine.

I already analyzed the cobalt code and cobalt have widevine code in src/startboard/shared/widevine

Please support for the below

1. How to enable the widevine in cobalt?
2. Sample page for widevine drm testing
3. Sample stream for widevine drm testing..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Someone please help me

Comment: You are going to face the same kind of issues as with an Electron app, I think - have a look at their notes here: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/testing-widevine-cdm

Answer (score 1):

The DrmSystemWidevine implementation we provide is for reference only.  You'll need your own Widevine (ce-cdm) implementation and use our DrmSystemWidevine implementation as a reference to implement the SbDrmSystem interface on top of it.

Any YouTube premium content can be used for testing, like [Frozen](https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=XfRY0ASZHuU).

Comment: It seems like the porting layer for widevine looks different from the chromium's one.
The chromium source has been implemented to dlopen the cdm library and call the ce_cdm wrapper apis, hence it could be running widevine contents by just copying the widevinecdm library file from the official chrome's. But colbalt seems that we need to have the widevinecdm source in advance before the cobalt built.
Is there any way cobalt can use chrome's widevinecdm prebuilt binary as it is?

Comment: There is nothing prevent us from using dlopen to load a cdm library in the Starboard implementation.  However, you will have to map SbDrm calls to the interface exposed by chrome's widevinecdm binary.